# installation and configuration

Tags: installation

I have in fact two questions.
Imagine that I install a new package, a driver or I change something in the screen configuration, and after rebooting I have some troubles for example nothing appears on the screen or unity configuration changed. Is there a clean way to save a general configuration of the system and then to come back to this one if I did some mistakes?

How can I reinstall my ubuntu without loosing my emails (thunderbird) and my documents? Any suggestion will be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Concerning your thunderbird question: all your mails and mailing settings are stored in your homefolder in `~/.thunderbird` (that's `/home/$YOURUSERNAME/.thunderbird`). Just backup this folder and paste it in the same direction on a clean install and you are able to continue with Thunderbird, where you left.

The dot in the folder-name indicates that the folder is hidden. You therefore normally won't see this folder. To display hidden folders, you may press `[CTRL]`+`[H]` in `nautilus`.

For your documents you would logically backup your Documents folder in your home-directory (however it is on your system called as it is localized).

And to installation faults: I don't know if there is something like a snapshot possibility but if you have installed a wrong package or such and don't see a thing, you may want to remember that you are using a Linux system. Press `[CTRL]`+`[ALT]`+`[F1]` to enter your first tty. This will work no matter if your xserver is acting faulty or not. From there you can revert any changes you made like you would do it in the terminal.